# Using access token on graph api

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get JSON data from this [url](http://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/awaaziitkgp/feed).
As you can see I need access token to get this.
So far I am able to login to facebook and get user access token

```
 `fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnFbError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnComplete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    Editor editor=sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    try {
                        updateButtonImage();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsFeed.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }`
```

How to use this access token to access the json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Facebook SDK you can manage authentication and token by the Session class. getAccessToken() method in session class is responsible to provide token.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null && session.getState().isOpened()){
    Log.i("sessionToken", session.getAccessToken());
    Log.i("sessionTokenDueDate", session.getExpirationDate().toLocaleString());
}
```

By using this access token u can get user image as:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=<your_access_token_here>
```

Comment: I already have the access token, the problem is that I dont know how to make use of it while making request to graph api.